# Setting extended class base class values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having a bit of a comprehension issue with mapping values from an instance of a base class to an extended class. Is there a way to do this without specifying all of the individual properties in a constructor? I don't want to do that in case more optional params are added to the base class by other developers. (Also there are about 20 of these classes each with 30+ properties)

Given the following code, what is the best way to set the values of my extended class without 'breaking' typescript.

```
export class BaseClass {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

export class ExtendClass extends BaseClass {
    d: string;
    e: string;
}


const exampleBase = {
    a: 'help',
    b: 'me',
    c: 'please',
};

let exampleExtend: ExtendClass = exampleBase; // Is there a way do this ??
exampleExtend.d = 'hello';
exampleExtend.e = 'world';

let exampleExtend2: any = exampleBase; // Breaking typing
exampleExtend2.d = 'hello';
exampleExtend2.e = 'world';
```

I was wondering if there was perhaps a way to achieve this with constructors, but can't see a way to assign a class to a parameter being passed in... Probably because this is mental.

```
export class BaseClass {
    constructor(values?: BaseClass) {
        if (values) {
            this = values; // Is there a way to do this? I think not and for good reason.
        }
    }
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

export class ExtendClass extends BaseClass {

    constructor(values: BaseClass) {
        super(values);
    }
    d: string;
    e: string;
}
```

Comment: `// Is there a way do this ??` -> `let exampleExtend: ExtendClass = <ExtendClass> exampleBase;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a clean constructor and `Object.assign`

```
class Bar {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;

    constructor(obj) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
}

let bar = new Bar({a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz'});

console.log(bar.a);
```

Answer (score 1):

@baao solution will work,..  But one problem is you could pass `{a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz', oops: 'oops'}`  And you have now got a property called oops on your object, basically you have lost the type checking of typescript.

One way around this is to use an interface, your constructor could then use this.

eg.

```
interface BarImp {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;    
}

class Bar implements BarImp {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    constructor(obj: BarImp) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
}

let bar = new Bar({a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz'});

//but this will still fail.
//let bar = new Bar({a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz', oops: 'oops'});  

console.log(bar.a);
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution to me! Fortunately for my use case @baao solution is good enough because I have other code stripping out extra properties up front before the extended class gets instantiated.

Why can't I just use my base class as the type rather than a separate interface? 

constructor(obj: BaseClass) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }

Comment: @Ravendarksky `Why can't I just use my base class as the type rather than a separate interface?`  You can do, but as soon as you start adding methods to `Bar`, all these methods will need to be part of object you send too.   IOW: if you add a method called `test` to `Bar`, you will now need to send `{a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz', test: function () {}}` etc.

Comment: Yes. It's better to use the interface like you did here - that's more typescript and type safe in contrary to mine.